How can I choose a database based on company id?
I have exacly the same two databases (in the feature I can have them more). The first database has data of company X and the second database has data of company Y. Is there any solution how can I choose which database I want to use based on company id?
Because now I have to create as many DBContext classes as I have databases although each database is the same. Is any other way or not?
// the first DbContext for company X:
    public class MyDatabase1 : DbContext, IMyDatabase
    {
            public MyDatabase1 (DbContextOptions<MyDatabase1> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }
    
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } = default!;
    }
    
// the second DbContext for company Y:
    public class MyDatabase2 : DbContext, IMyDatabase
    {
            public MyDatabase2 (DbContextOptions<MyDatabase2> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }
    
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } = default!;
    }
    
    public interface IMyDatabase
    {
        DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

And then I have to register it in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDatabase1>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase1")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDatabase2>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase2")));

I use it in that way:
public class DatabaseStrategy
{
    private readonly MyDatabase1 _context1;
    private readonly MyDatabase2 _context2;

    public DatabaseStrategy(MyDatabase1 context1, MyDatabase2 context2)
    {
        _context1 = context1;
        _context2 = context2;
    }

    public IMyDatabase GetDatabase(int companyId)
    {
        if (companyId == 1)
        { 
            return _context1; 
        }
        else if (companyId == 2)
        {
            return _context2;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

builder.Services.AddScoped<DatabaseStrategy>();

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PostsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DatabaseStrategy _databaseStrategy;

    public PostsController(DatabaseStrategy databaseStrategy)
    {
        _databaseStrategy = databaseStrategy;                
    }

    public ActionResult<List<Post>> Get()
    {
        var companyId = 1;
        var databaseStrategy = _databaseStrategy.GetDatabase(companyId);

        var result = databaseStrategy.Posts.ToList();
        return result;
    }
}


How will you know which database to hit based on a customer? If you have a way to do that, you could dynamically add the database name to the connection string in the factory/strategy. Just make sure it doesn't get shared across requests. I'm assuming you are targeting SQL Server based on the code, and that the databases are on the same server. If they're on separate servers, you can do the same thing with the db host, etc., but you'd need a static place to look up the connection information either way.

You need create single DbContext.cs class like below :
public class MyDatabase : DbContext, IMyDatabase
{
    public MyDatabase(DbContextOptions<MyDatabase> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; } = default!;
}

And in appsettings.json specify the two connection string like below:
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "Company1": "Server=server1;Database=company1_db;User Id=user;Password=password;",
        "Company2": "Server=server2;Database=company2_db;User Id=user;Password=password;"
    }
}

Afterward, create DBContextFactory.cs class which relies on the company id like below:
public class DbContextFactory
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DbContextFactory(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public MyDatabase CreateDbContext(int companyId)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDatabase>();
        var connectionString = GetConnectionString(companyId);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new MyDatabase(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }

    private string GetConnectionString(int companyId)
    {
        return companyId switch
        {
            1 => _configuration.GetConnectionString("Company1"),
            2 => _configuration.GetConnectionString("Company2"),
            _ => throw new Exception("Invalid company ID")
        };
    }
}

Don't forget to register DbContextFactory.cs class in your program.cs like below
builder.Services.AddSingleton<DbContextFactory>();

Now you can modify your DatabaseStrategy.cs class to dynamically get the DbContext by passing the company ID like below :
public class DatabaseStrategy
{
    private readonly DbContextFactory _dbContextFactory;

    public DatabaseStrategy(DbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public IMyDatabase GetDatabase(int companyId)
    {
        return _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(companyId);
    }
}

Finally, at the controller level expose the endpoint to pass List<Posts> via controller
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PostsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DatabaseStrategy _databaseStrategy;

    public PostsController(DatabaseStrategy databaseStrategy)
    {
        _databaseStrategy = databaseStrategy;                
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Post>> Get(int companyId)
    {
        var database = _databaseStrategy.GetDatabase(companyId);
        var result = database.Posts.ToList();
        return result;
    }
}

Note: It's not the best practice to expose your DatabaseStrategy.cs directly in your controller. Therefore it's better to add an additional service level between DatabaseStrategy.cs and your API controller.

Man, this is EXACLY what I needed! Thank you VERY VERY MUCH :)
